# Use OrderBy doesnt work CodeIgniter Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine, sql-order-by, query-builder

Good morning,

I have this function to order my products by 'most expensive' and 'most cheap', and It's working fine, but the problem is, I have some products without image and I want them be moved to the last page, when I do the follow:

```
              ->addOrderBy('u.status','desc')
              ->addOrderBy('u.imagem', 'DESC')
              ->addOrderBy($order,$for)
              ->getQuery()
```

He move the product without images to the last page, But doesnt work my OrderBy to order by Most Expensive and Cheap.

When `

```
            ->addOrderBy('u.status','desc')
            ->addOrderBy($order,$for)
            ->addOrderBy('u.imagem', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
```

Works fine but images continue random.

[image]

Comment: what is the value of the `u.imagem` field when a product does not have an image? what is the field type for `u.imagem` in the table?

Comment: The type is string, the value when does not have an image is NULL.

Comment: I wrote an answer for you. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but doesnt work. When I try the second option (the one that I need), he actualy order right, with the images for last, but my first OrderBy($order, $for) doesnt work like it should, It's like if he overwrite the first orderBy.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `u.imagem` field is null when the product has no image, you could:

1.- If you want to inhibit the products without images from the results:

Add a `where` clause for `u.imagem IS NOT NULL` and you'll only be returned results that have images.

2.- If all you want/need is to keep the products with no image in the listing but at the end, you can:

```
        ->addOrderBy('u.status','desc')
        ->addOrderBy($order,$for)
        ->addOrderBy('u.imagem IS NULL', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
```

The above works because `IS NULL` returns a 0 when false and a 1 when true. By sorting those 1s and 0s in ascending order, you'll get all the ones that don't satisfy `IS NULL` (i.e., the ones that actually have images) first, then the others

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but doesnt work. When I try the second option (the one that I need), he actualy order right, with the images for last, but my first OrderBy($order, $for) doesnt work like it should, It's like if he overwrite the first orderBy.